# Build dynamic predicate based on generic type

Tags: c#, linq, generics

How do I make this expression dynamic based on the generic type passed in the parameter?

In the simplified form:

```
public static class CompareService
{

    public static List<T> Run<T>(List<T> database_list, string directory_path)
    {          
            var csv_list = CompareService.MergeRecordsFromFiles<T>(directory);
            return CompareService.RunComparison<T>(database_list, csv_list);
    }

    public static T CompareData<T>(List<T> database_list, List<T> csv_list)
    {           
            var diff = new List<T>();

            foreach (var db_item in database_list)
            {
                // ...
                // if T is of type Deathstar compare reference_number property
                // if T is of type Stormtrooper compare id property
                // if T is of type Sith compare id and anger_level property                
                var csv_item = csv_list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.reference_number == db_item.reference_number);
                // Comparison code
                ComparisonResult result = compareLogic.Compare(db_item, csv_item);
                // ...
            }
            return diff;
    }    
}
```

It is called from another generic service:

```
public static void Whatever<T>(List<T> list)
{
    // ...
    var directory_path = "C:\";
    var delta = CompareService.CompareData<T>(list, directory_path);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Your method naming isn't exactly precise. Perhaps you meant to call it `GetByReferenceNumber()` or something similar? Also, this means you can replace the `Where()` clause directly with a `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Do you have a typo there? `list` the parameter is `database_list` in the body of the function?

Comment: I also think you need to elaborate more on the use case

Comment: I've just have. Basically this service is 100% generic except the predicate part.

Answer (score 2):

The most naive implementation would be to check if your `itemToFind` can be cast to `DeathStar`, `StormTrooper` or `Sith` and if so call the instances property.

```
var deathStar  = itemToFind as DeathStar;
if(deathStar != null)
    return database_list.Where(x => ((DeathStar)x).reference_number == deathStar.reference_number).FirstOrDefault();
else
{
    var sith = itemToFind as Sith;
    if(sith != null)
        return database_list.Where(x => ((Sith)x).anger_level == sith.anger_level).FirstOrDefault();
    else
        return database_list.Where(x => ((StormTrooper)x).id== ((StormTrooper)item).id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This is quite cumbersome, including many casts. In particular it completely bypasses the actual benefits of generics using any arbitrary type (that fullfills the constraints if existing). In your case you´d have a generic method that will only wortk for three decent types.

A better approach is to let all your classes implement a common interface that defines a property, for instance:

```
interface IObject {
    int Level { get; }
}
```

Now all classes define that `level`-property:

```
clas DeathStar : IObject
{
    public int Level { get { return this.reference_number; } }
}
clas Sith : IObject
{
    public int Level { get { return this.anger_level; } }
}
clas StormTrooper: IObject
{
    public int Level { get { return this.id; } }
}
```

Than you can use a constraint on your type `T` to implement that interface:

```
public static T CompareData<T>(List<T> list, T itemToFind) where T: IObject
```

Comment: I like the second approach. But the first feels really strange, to declare a _generic_ method and then _check_ the type is (for me) typically a sign of a design flaw.

Comment: @RenéVogt That´s true, it´s the most naive implementation, not neccessarily the best.

Comment: Your first approach won't work as T is generic and does not contain definition of reference_number or any property.

Comment: I've just edited the question. This service is 100% generic except when I need to loop through items in the list and and compare property values.

Comment: That's great but up to the point where I have to compare different properties of different types.

Comment: @KlaatuVerataNecto Why? with this approach you only compare the `Level` property (i'm talking about the second approach here)

Answer (score 0):

Why not like this:

```
public static T CompareData<T>(List<T> list, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return database_list.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
var itemToFind = new ItemToFind();
var myObjectList = new List<MyObject>();
var item = CompareData<MyObject>(myObjectList, x=> x.MyObjectProperty == itemToFind.Id);
```

Comment: Why then he needs your function? He can directly use `database_list.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.MyObjectProperty == itemToFind.Id)`

Comment: True, but his description was not specific. This function is useful if you choose to make it an extension method or a service implementation for a service interface that exposes that dynamic method.

Comment: You have taken out  `T itemToFind` parameter.

Comment: You don't need it, the `itemToFind` is now used directly to query the list. In my example `T itemToFind` is `var itemToFind = new ItemToFind();`. Of course you don't have to use `new` there, that can be a view model.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a property selector:

```
public static class CompareService
{
    public static T CompareData<T>(this List<T> list, T itemToFind, Func<T, int> propSelector)
    {
        int propToFind = propSelector(itemToFind); // cache
        return database_list.FirstOrDefault(x => propSelector(x) == propToFind);
    } 
}
```

And call it like that:

```
listOfDeathstars.CompareData(deathStarToFind, ds => ds.reference_number);
listOfStormtroopers.CompareData(trooperToFind, t => t.id);
listOfSiths.CompareData(sithStarToFind, sith => new { sith.id, sith.anger_level});
```

---

Note: I added the `this` keyword in the signature to make it an extension (not sure if you intended that but forgot the keyword). And `Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault()` can be reduced to `FirstOrDefault(predicate)`.